# Scatter diagrams with group labels for X/Y coordinates

Tags: microsoft-excel-2003, charts

I'M trying to create a map layout from an Excel spreadsheet in Excel 2003.

I have x and y coordinates in columns as well as group name and place name. I tried using a scatter chart but I can only display x, y coords or series names.

How can add I get the group name or place name to appear in the scatter diagram?

Answer (score 1):

I’m not sure I entirely understand your question, and I have only Excel 2007 to play with, so my findings might be of no value to you. 
But I did accomplish something that seems to be what I guess you want:

[image]

You obviously already know how to create the scatter chart.  What I did next was:

- Click somewhere in the chart.  (Remember that Microsoft Office 2007 and above uses the “ribbon”.  In Excel 2007, when you click in a chart, three new tabs appear on the ribbon: “Design”, “Layout”, and “Format”.)
- Go to the “Layout” tab.
- Find the “Labels” function group, and click on either the “Chart Title” or the “Axis Titles” button.  They both have drop-down menus.  The “Chart Title” drop-down menu lists “Centered Overlay Title” and “Above Chart”; the “Axis Titles” drop-down menu lists “Primary Horizontal Axis Title” and “Primary Vertical Axis Title” (and both of ***those*** have pull-right menus, which are self-explanatory). 
  I selected “Primary Horizontal Axis Title”; “**Axis Title**” appeared below the X axis.
- Click on the title.
- Click in the formula bar, and enter the value you want for the label. 
  Cell references must be fully qualified, so, in the above example, I used `=Sheet1!D1`.

Good luck finding the equivalent functions in Excel 2003. 
(And if you do, please post them as another answer.)

---

*Not added by OP.* One way to to insert a label could be to add another 'series' (ie ColumnD above) move its legend, format to hide series marker and adjust other formats:

[image]